# No puedo visualizar VIEW en PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas, en una de mis aplicaciones necesito acceder a la View de la tabla, pero por algún motivo, parece que el usario no tiene acceso.

Cuando trato de acceder a través de phpMyAdmin me lanza el siguiente error

```
error #1045 - access denied for user 'qma_2017'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Al resto de las tablas y demás puedo acceder sin problema. He probado también a darle todos los permisos al usario y nada de nada.

¿Alguna idea? 
Gracias!

Comment: con usuario root pudiste verlo?,puede que tengas que cambiar permisos a la vista

Comment: Buenas JackNavaRow. Tanto con root como con admin me da otro error ( #1449 - The user specified as a definer ('root'@'%') does not exist) ¿Dónde puedo cambiarle los permisos a las vistas? Gracias!

Comment: ('root'@'localhost') es el usuario, como creastes la View a traves de un sql o del mismo phpmyadmin?

Comment: tu problema es de usuarios puede que creastes el usuario 'qma_2017'@'%' y no 'qma_2017'@'localhost'

Comment: en realidad no la cree yo (es un proyecto heredado) yo solo lo he migrado de un servidor a otro. En el otro funciona... en el nuevo no. Pero supongo que se creó a través de SQL

Comment: migrastes tambien los usuarios?

Comment: CREATE USER 'qma_2017'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'CLAVE';  luego haz esto GRANT ALL ON TUBASEDEDATOS.* TO  'qma_2017'@'localhost'; y despues FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Gracias JackNavaRow, pero no era eso, sigue sin dejarme acceder a las VIEWS.

Comment: hazlo con root CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'CLAVE';

Comment: Tampoco, no creo que el problema sea la definición del user, debe ser otra cosa, desgraciadamente no tengo ninguna pista más sobre qué puede ser :(

Comment: Ejecuta lo siguiente **SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;** y comprueba que usuarios existen es posible que tengas algún conflicto o usuarios duplicados o anonimos

Comment: Gracias Xerif. Demonios espero que no sea eso! En este servidor tengo alojadas casi 80 webs y cada base de datos tiene un usario diferente así que tengo más de 80 usuarios. No sé si alguno estará generando conflictos, pero no los hay duplicados ni aninimos

Comment: carga la base de datos mysql del servidor antiguo como ultima opcion

Comment: ¿Sabes que las consultas escritas son más rápidas y eficaces que las VIEWS?

Comment: No mates al mensajero :p. La app usa las VIEWS, yo no desarrolle la app, soy esclavo de sus caprichos!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente logré arreglar el problema... Pero sigo sin saber que lo ocasionaba. En vez de importar toda la base de datos, borre la vista y la recree manualmente... y comenzó a funcionar. Gracias a JackNavaRow y Xerif por la ayuda!